# How to load large amount of document in android using media store

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am loading all document from storage using media store query and fetching from background using coroutines scope but it can take delay of 3-4 seconds to load all files from storage

I have trying changing query of media store but it can not work i have seen multiple apps in play store and it can load data fast if files is more 10,000 or more i want to load all files like those apps

Comment: In what do you load them?

Comment: i am load them into recylerview

Comment: You will not load complete files i think. You will only display their file names i think. So you are just listing them. Not loading.

Comment: You don't understand brother i want to load all pdf and other files like this reference app this app load smooth all files

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imagetopdf.pdfconverter.jpgtopdf.pdfeditor&hl=en

Comment: You are not even telling the name of the app. Or what it is. A file explorer/manager? I have no access to store so tell.

Comment: You dont get it. One can load a txt file in a text editor. One can load an image file in an ImageView. But i think you only want to list files and display the list in a recycle view. But no file will be opened/read/loaded. Load 10.000 files? Impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.